# copy all rows of a table to another table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two databases in `MySQL` and `SQL Server`, and I want to create tables in `SQL Server` and copy all rows from the table in `MySQL` into the new table in `SQL Server`.

I can create table in `SQL Server` same as `MySQL`, with this code:

```
List<String> TableNames = new List<string>();
{ 
    IDataReader reader= 
        ExecuteReader("SELECT Table_Name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'mavara%'",MySql);
    while (reader.Read()) {
        TableNames.Add(reader[0].ToString());
    }
    reader.Close();
}

foreach (string TableName in TableNames) {
    IDataReader reader = 
        ExecuteReader("SELECT Column_Name,IS_NULLABLE,DATA_TYPE FROM information_schema.columns where TABLE_Name='" + TableName + "'",MySql);
    List<string[]> Columns = new List<string[]>();
    while (reader.Read()) { 
        string[] column = new string[3];
        column[0] = reader[0].ToString();
        column[1] = reader[1].ToString();
        column[2] = reader[2].ToString();
        Columns.Add(column);
    }

    reader.Close();

    // create table
    string  queryCreatTables=  "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + TableName + "](\n";
    foreach(string[] cols in Columns)
    {
        queryCreatTables +="["+ cols[0] + "] " + cols[2] + " ";
        if (cols[1] == "NO")
            queryCreatTables += "NOT NULL";
        // else
        //   queryCreatTables += "NULL";
        queryCreatTables += " ,\n ";
    }
    queryCreatTables += ")";

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand smd = 
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryCreatTables, MsSql);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader sreader = smd.ExecuteReader();
    sreader.Close();
```

but I have problem to copy rows from one table into another table.

for select query, I use Idatareader, but I don't know how insert rows to another table.

Comment: This sounds like something that would really better be handled at the DBMS level. Or is this migration something that's undertaken often and you need a program to automate the procedure?

Comment: yes. I need a program to handle that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is as follows:

```
1. For each table in source database
2.    Get a list of columns for that table
3.    Create table in destination database
4.    SELECT * FROM the table in source
5.    For each row in data
6.       Generate INSERT statement and execute on destination database
```

The information you need for a column is `Name`, `Type`, `Length`, etc.

Then you generate the insert statement by iterating on the columns

```
var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES( ";
foreach( var column in columns )
    insertStatement += "@" + column.Name + ",";
insertStatement[insertStatement.Length-1] = ')';

var command = new SqlCommand( insertStatement, MsSql );

// iterate over the columns again, but this time set values to the parameters
foreach( var column in columns )
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@"+column.Name, currentRow[column.Name] );
```

Answer (score 2):

For inserting rows from one table into another table please refer the below  sample query

```
    INSERT INTO Store_Information (store_name, Sales, Date)
    SELECT store_name, sum(Sales), Date
     FROM Sales_Information
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I have a problem to copy rows from one table into another table.

You can use the [`SqlDataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xw5z0hdd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to [perform Batch Updates/Inserts with a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbbwt18a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) against the database to copy the data from one table to the other. After you get all records from the first MYSQL table using something like:

```
//Get the rows from the first mysql table as you did in your question
DataTable mysqlfirstTableRowsTobeCopied = GetDataTableFromMySQLTable();
```

Then you have to create a commend text that do the `INSERT` something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TableName Column_Name, ... VALUES(...)";
```

Or you can use a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_BatchInsert ( @ColumnName VARCHAR(20), ... ) 
AS 
BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO TableName VALUES ( @ColumnNamne, ...); 
END
```

Then:

```
DataTable mysqlfirstTableRowsTobeCopied = GetDataTableFromMySQLTable();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_BatchInsert", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

// Set the Parameter with appropriate Source Column Name
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50,
    mysqlfirstTableRowsTobeCopied.Columns[0].ColumnName);   
...
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
adpt.InsertCommand = cmd;
// Specify the number of records to be Inserted/Updated in one go. Default is 1.
adpt.UpdateBatchSize = 20;

conn.Open();
int recordsInserted = adpt.Update(mysqlfirstTableRowsTobeCopied);   
conn.Close();
```

This code actually is quoted from a full tutorial about this subject in the codeproject, you can refer to it for more information:

- [Multiple Ways to do Multiple Inserts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25457/Multiple-Ways-to-do-Multiple-Inserts)

Comment: i read this article but i don't know column name and its type to insert query

Comment: @atabrizi, Refer to the MS Sql server Management studio to figure out its name and its data type, then choose the ADO.NET data type that correspond to that type.

Comment: if you read my code, you can see i creat table from mysql table and i dont know name of columns . and i have 170 tables.i need program to handle all of this tables

Comment: @atabrizi, You can get the column name and data type of the columns from your mysql database. But do you want to do the same thing for those 170 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a datatable with rows that you want to merge with another table...

There are two ways to do this...again, assuming you've already selected the data and put it into a new table.

```
            oldTable.Load(newTable.CreateDataReader());

            oldTable.Merge(newTable);
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually that's sth. you can do in SQL directly: `INSERT INTO table FROM SELECT * FROM othertable`;

Comment: one of my tables was into sql server and another was in mysql and i cant use this code

Answer (score -1):

For insertion of all record into new table(If the second table is not exist)

Select * into New_Table_Name from Old_Table_Name;

For insertion of all records into Second Table(If second table is exist But the table structure should be same)

Insert into Second_Table_Name from(Select * from First_Table_Name);

Answer (score -1):

Just in case it can help someone, I've found an easy way to do it in C# using SqlDataAdapter. It automatically detects the structure of the table so you don't have to enumerate all the columns or worry about table structure changing. Then bulk inserts the data in the destination table.

As long as the two tables have the same structure, this will work. (For example, copying from a production table to a dev empty table.)

```
using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringFromDatabase))
    {
      sqlConn.Open();
      using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}].[{1}]", schemaName, tableName), sqlConn))
      {
        adapter.Fill(table);
      };
    }

    using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringDestination))
    {
      sqlConn.Open();
      // perform bulk insert
      using(var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity|SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls, null))
      {
        foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
          bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
        }
        bulk.DestinationTableName = String.Format("[{0}].[{1}]", schemaName, tableName);
        bulk.WriteToServer(table);
      }
    }
```